# JSTL foreach displays the var name instead of it's value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jstl

Hello I am learning Java EE, and now I am on the JSTL part. I am trying to display the variable value using a foreach loop, but the result is always the variable name instead of its value .
I searched on the net but I haven't found anything that seems to be helpful.
Here is my index.jsp code :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body>

        <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="10">
            ${i}
            <c:if test="${i%2==0}">
                <p class="text-primary"><c:out value="${i}"/>></p>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${i%2!=0}">
                <p class="text-success"><c:out value="${i}"/>></p>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result given by this is : 
[image: The result of the code]

P.S: I am using maven and the jstl jar is imported I am using 1.2 version. I also tried different versions but in vain.
I am using Intellij Ultimate version, this code is working perfectly on Eclipse yet not on Intellij.
Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`
 to `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`
But what is the difference between the two links and why it is working when changing it?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You normally display it with tags : `<%= i %>`, or using `<c:out value="i" />.`

Comment: <c:out value="i" />`does not display the value of "i", it displays only the variable name as well . And for the <%= i %> will oblige you te create a variable other than the one has been created in foreach